# TypeError: Cannot read property 'existsSync' of undefined - Web Development with Node and Express - Ethan Brown - ch13

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, mongodb, express

I'm super new to GitHub, as well as to MEAN (mongodb, express, angular, node.js), I'm following a book by Ethan Brown- Web Development with Node and Express  and he provided a git repository to be cloned and followed.

https://github.com/EthanRBrown/web-development-with-node-and-express

I'm on chapter 13 and I've been getting this error.

```
meadowlark.js:428
if(!fs.existsSync(dataDir)) fs.mkdirSync(dataDir);
      ^
```

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'existsSync' of undefined

my **meadowlark.js** file at jsfiddle:

[jsfiddle.net/tawc0qdh/](http://jsfiddle.net/tawc0qdh/)

Can you please help? I really appreciate your time.

Comment: So why don't you post the code snipplet around it... And stackoverflow has a snipplet tool just like jsfiddle. I glanced quickly at the fiddle and did not see it in all that code. Where is fs defined?

Comment: were you include **fs** in your project? like **var fs = require('fs');**

Comment: var fs = require('fs'); is on 545, it was supposed to be before if(!fs.existsSync(dataDir)) fs.mkdirSync(dataDir); right?   Sorry about not using SO snipplet tool.

Comment: I moved var fs and now i get this error:

Comment: C:\ch12\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\mongodb\lib\utils.js:98
    process.nextTick(function() { throw err; });
                                  ^
MongoError: Authentication failed.
    at Function.MongoError.create (C:\ch12\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\mongodb\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\error.js:31:11)